# How to differentiate devices for building socket connection

Tags: java, http, sockets, tcp, ip

I'm currently building an application using TCP/IP connection and app establishes connection between server and client by querying an ip address from mysql database. But let's say there are

people A and B connected to a network NET_A (220.241.XXX.XXX)

AND

people C and D connected to a network NET_B (221.221.xxx.xxx)

and if I want A and D to be connected using some sort of ip address and B and C to be connected to each others, then what kind of ip address or method should I have to use so that those people can successfully connect to each others? I've successfully connected A and B in network NET_A using local IPv4 address achieved using following code:

```
InetAddress thisIp =InetAddress.getLocalHost();
System.out.println("IP:"+thisIp.getHostAddress());
```

Also following is serversocket code:

```
   ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(PORT);
   ss.setSoTimeout(10000);
   connection = ss.accept();
```

Follow is client socket code:

```
connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP), PORT);
```

Comment: What you need is not 'some sort of IP address' but a functioning *route* between the two networks. It might even involve installing some hardware.

Comment: Also it is worth mentioning that these IP addresses are not in the private range. The private ranges are `10.0.0.0/8 (255.0.0.0)`, `172.16.0.0/12 (255.240.0.0)` and `192.168.0.0/16 (255.255.0.0)`.

Comment: Why are you doing this anyhow? It seems strange.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a router with an IP in both networks and add a route to all hosts telling them about the remote network and the IP address of the router (gateway).

You can setup a linux machine to do this easily by enabling packet forwarding. Just add `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` to `/etc/sysctl.conf` and run `sudo sysctl -p`

As a socket programmer routing is not normally something you need to care about, it is done for you.